# Why are the angles on my concentric circles increasingly smaller?

Tags: objective-c, ios

The first circle that is drawn (the innermost one) is OK, but then they get increasingly less circular? I know this must have something to do with the iterations.

```
//LOAD CIRCLES

circleWidth = 100;
circleHeight = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
circleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight);
circleView.center = self.view.center;
circleView.alpha = 0.7;
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
circleView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
circleView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
circleHeight += 50;
circleWidth += 50;

[self.view addSubview:circleView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:circleView];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're increasing the width and height in each iteration, but the `cornerRadius` remains fixed at 50, which will only result in a circle if width and height are 100 (first iteration). You should set the `cornerRadius` to `circleWidth * 0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the cornerRadius to at least half of `circleHeight`:

```
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleHeight * 0.5f;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it has to do circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 50 -- you're incrementing the circleHeight and circleWidth but not the cornerRadius